# Same PDF file to show and download

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pdf, download

I am looking for way to process same PDF file (located on a host with apache server) by two different ways. First - by default, if I click the link http://example.com/1.pdf, this file should be open in browser to read or print (it is already working). Second - if I click the link like http://example.com/1.pdf?download this file should be downloaded as a binary file.

I guess it could be done by .htaccess magic, but I am not too smart to guess how to do it exactly. Can you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220059/set-referrer-header-using-query-string-on-apache-configuration  but use the force-download header instead of setting the referer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} download
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pdf$
RequestHeader Set "Content-Disposition" "attachment"
```

Comment: can always add in a null rewriterule, e.g. `RewriteRule .* $1` or whatever.